# Call a Function with inline ASM

Tags: c, assembly, inline-assembly

is there a way to call **MessageBox**, by using inline assembly?

```
#include<windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"user32.lib");

int main()
{
    MessageBox(0,"Hello","Title",1);
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: The links you are providing are great but "Sleep" has only one argument. I need a way to pass multiple arguments to the functions i need to call. Like the MessageBox function.

Comment: [How do you call Win32 API functions from inline assembler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917196/how-do-you-call-win32-api-functions-from-inline-assembler)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you call Win32 API functions from inline assembler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917196/how-do-you-call-win32-api-functions-from-inline-assembler)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp It sounds like you found an exact duplicate. Why not voting to close as such? :)

Comment: Sorry, but MessageBox has multiple arguments. The links you guys are mentioning are single-argument examples.

Comment: @CDoc - If you have one argument, you push it on the stack and then `CALL` the function. Now try to generalize this for two arguments!

Comment: What compiler are you using and does it have an option to leave intermediate files?  Some compilers will leave an assembly listing `.lst` file after the compile if you tell it to.  You could take a look at that and see what it does.  It's `-S` for the GCC compiler and it's a `.s` output file.

Answer (score 1):

I think the comments on the question are pretty clear about how the actual call goes, now lets see how the arguments are passed.

This is a direct question about the Microsoft ABI. It is as follows-

The first 4 arguments are passed in the register %rcx, %rdx, %r8, %r9 and the remaining are passed on the stack.
So the rest can be pushed on the stack with the 5th on the top and the 6th below it.

Now there is one peculiarity you have to be careful about. You have to also leave space on the stack for the first 4 arguments. Which means that after call the 5th argument will be after 5 (8 byte) slots (1 for return address and 4 parameters).
You can achieve that by doing subq $32, %rsp after pushing the 5th argument.

This extra space is left for the callee to swap the registers out in case it needs to use them.

So for your case,

`movq $0, %rcx`

`movq $hello, %rdx`

`movq $title, %r8`

`movq $1, %r9`

`callq MessageBox`

PS: This example is written keeping 64 bit architecture and AT&T syntax.
Also the ABI is not the same for *NIX environments.
Hope this helps.

EDIT: infact it is better to always leave space on the stack before calling a function with the fast call convention because they might swap the registers and you don't want your stack frame to be overwritten.

Comment: Your code snippet looks like it's un-optimized compiler output.  `xor %ecx,%ecx` would be better than `mov $0`.  And the last `mov` should be `mov $1, %r9d`, to save another byte.

Comment: re: last point: yes it's required that you leave 32B of "shadow space" on the stack before a function call in Windows x64 `__fastcall` and `__vectorcall`, even for functions with no args.